# SQL, incrementing column value returned from SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM table_one
WHERE y='asd'
ORDER BY z ASC;
```

Hi, I'm querying my database using the query above, upon the return of the query I'd like to increment z by 1 (not update it but just increment it so it shows in the result). I don't want to do an Update statement, this is just temporary and should only be visible in the query result.

How would I go about doing this? It's for a school assignment. I've tried to use REPLACE without any success. What works is changing z to z+1 but then the column name changes to ?column? instead of z.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can say `z+1 as z`

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Yeah, Googling for 30 minutes led to nothing, and it was this simple. Thank you, worked great! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need add column alias:

```
SELECT x, y, z + 1 AS z    -- here
FROM table_one
WHERE y='asd'
ORDER BY z ASC;
```